# Query term in tags function in select2 3.4

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-select2

This code wokrs well with select2 3.2 for generating multiselect box with ajax autocomplete (like http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#token but with sugestions dinamic loading)

```
$("#forTags").select2({
      minimumInputLength: 2,
      tokenSeparators:[','],
      multiple: true,
      tags:function (query) {
        if (!query) return;
        var q = query.term;
        //some ajax call 
      }
    });
```

But after upgrade to 3.4.5 version query parameter is missing. No parameter in function call **data()**:

```
  function tags(data) {
    var isFunc = $.isFunction(data);
    return function (query) {
      var t = query.term, filtered = {results: []};
      $(isFunc ? data() : data).each(function () {
        var isObject = this.text !== undefined,
          text = isObject ? this.text : this;
        if (t === "" || query.matcher(t, text)) {
          filtered.results.push(isObject ? this : {id: this, text: this});
        }
      });
      query.callback(filtered);
    };
  }
```

What is the rigth way for creating multiselect box with ajax autocomplete in new version of select2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is bug of select2

https://github.com/ckan/ckan/issues/1512

hopefully will be fixed soon

Comment: fixed at select2 3.4.8